# ldap not properly resolving host

Tags: domain-name-system, ldap, openldap

I just changed the IP address of my (openldap) ldap server and despite DNS propagating, ldap still isn't resolving the new address correctly.  When I run "host myserver.com" the proper ip address is returned.  There is no entry in /etc/hosts for myserver.com.  But when I run:

ldapsearch -d 1 -x "uid" -H ldap://myserver.com

I see the old address.  How can I force ldap to check DNS for the proper IP address?

thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 2):

I knew that as soon as I asked I'd figure it out:

nscd --invalidate=hosts